# What's the best way to deal with Fractions in Cython?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have an np array with elements in Fractions form for machine precision. I want to apply linear algebra procedure like gaussian elimination. Here's the Cython code I have thus far (Note that it shows only the steps to get the upper triangle form, but doesn't actually rref it).

Generated Data in Python:

```
size = 5
foo = np.array([[Fc(v).limit_denominator(100) for v in r]
                for r in np.random.randn(size, size)])
identity = np.array([[Fc(v) for v in r] for r in np.identity(len(foo))])
m_id = np.concatenate([foo, identity], axis=1)
```

Cython:

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from quicktions import Fraction as Fc
cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
def invert_gaussian4(np.ndarray matrix):

    cdef int matrix_size = matrix.shape[1] // 2
    cdef int c_i
    cdef int r_i
    cdef int swap

    for c_i in range(matrix_size - 1):
        swap = np.argmax(np.abs(matrix[c_i:, c_i])) + c_i
        matrix[[swap, c_i]] = matrix[[c_i, swap]]
        row = matrix[c_i, :] / matrix[c_i, c_i]
        for r_i in range(c_i+1, matrix_size):
            del_row = row * matrix[r_i, c_i]
            matrix[r_i, :] = matrix[r_i, :] - del_row
```

Compared to Python, the performance of the Cython function doesn't improve that much. I already recognize that the the np function calls within the loop and fractions elements are what's slowing down the code. Any suggestions on how I could optimize this code better?

Comment: Your arrays are object dtype, and the objects are these `Fraction` objects.  So the `cython` code has to call `numpy` and `Fraction` functions repeatedly.  In other words, there's a lot that it convert to pure `c`.  Look at the annoated `c` code. You'll see a lot of yellow.

Comment: @hpaulj Is there a C equivalent functions to argmax and abs on an array? Or, would I need to write a function from scratch?

Comment: Why do you want to use fraction objects instead of floats?  Cython and NumPy are *much* better at optimizing floating point arithmetic.

Comment: The object array indexing `matrix[c_i:, c_i]` will also require calls to numpy code.

Comment: @Kevin, this is for my research task and it's actually critical to leave the values in fractions since floats are rounded arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

**You can have speed, or you can keep your extreme level of precision.  You need to make a decision.**

You've said in the comments that this data is used for "research" but have not specified the field.  In quite a few fields of research, data produced is not exact.  Instead, they are approximations you have obtained by taking measurements of real-world phenomena.  We say that each value has a number of significant figures.  These significant figures are propagated through the computation, and at the end, you are expected to round away any insignificant figures.

While floating point math does involve intermediate rounding, this rounding typically preserves more than enough significant figures that the end result is not affected.  For example, using 64-bit double-precision IEEE 754 floating point values (which Python does by default), your significand has 53 significant figures in base 2, which works out to [approx. 15](https://www.google.com/search?q=(log+2+/+log+10)*53) significant figures in base 10.  If your actual data only has, say, five significant figures, then you should not care about this intermediate rounding for most reasonable operations.

If this paragraph does describe what you are doing, then you should replace your fraction objects with standard floats.  This alone will enormously speed up your computation.

If this does not accurately describe what you are doing (e.g. because your field is some variety of pure mathematics or another theoretical discipline), then you may have little choice but to live with the slowness.  You might look at [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/), which is designed to do the kind of symbolic manipulation which these fields tend to focus on.

If you are using real-world data, but it has more than 15 significant figures, then you should be aware that 64-bit integers only go as high as ~10^18.  This means your fraction objects are quite possibly being implemented using arbitrary-precision integers, which are very slow indeed.  In this case, you want to be working with a (super-computing) platform that supports 128-bit integers and/or floats, and you probably do not want to be coding in Python (read: pre-compiled Python binaries may or may not exist for such a platform, and depending on its standards-conformance, they may or may not be possible to compile yourself; regardless the performance will be questionable at best).

Finally, you should not write your own Gaussian elimination routine.  Instead, use [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html).  This will probably be both faster and more precise.

Comment: The machine precision of gaussian elimination is absolutely critical for the matrix operation I need. The research involves satellite projection and I will not go into details beyond what I have laid out on my question given the sensitiveness of it.

Comment: @MLhacker: If you have more than 15 sig figs, then I added a note about how your fractions are probably too big to fit into machine-sized integers and are therefore even slower than they otherwise would be.

Comment: I understand that there's a trade-off between precision and speed, but I cannot sacrifice precision at the moment since there's an accuracy threshold I have to meet in my research objective and there is no way around it and super-computing, unfortunately, is not an environment I have access to at the moment.

Comment: @MLhacker: If you're going to round to *n* significant figures at the end of the process, for *n* < 15, then you are not sacrificing any precision, as I have explained.  If you're not going to round, then I'm afraid I do not understand the nature of your research.  Regardless, you may be able to make a few incremental improvements around the corners, but you will *not* make significant progress so long as your basic numerical primitives are being implemented in software rather than hardware.  It's just too expensive.

Comment: How about switching to a language where fractions are native. For example compiling lisp or scheme.

Comment: @hpaulj: That will still happen in software rather than hardware, so improvements will be marginal at best.  Frankly, "rewrite your code from scratch in language X" is only good advice if the benefits are huge.

Comment: You may be running into the performance limitations of Python's big number arithmetic. The GMP library will be faster for larger numbers. In `gmpy2` (which supports GMP, MPFR, and MPC), we have been adding Cython support. You will need to use the latest development code. You may need to look at the issue for examples, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This answer won't solve the problem, but will explain why you're having problems and possibly give you some clues on where you need to compromise. Essentially you have two problems:

### 1. You're using a numpy array of Python objects

Cython works best with numpy arrays if they are arrays consisting of a single integer or floating point type. Your array is made up of arbitrary Python objects (and hence in C each element of the array is a pointer to a separate memory location where the Python object is stored). This means that every indexing operation requires an incref and decref for reference counting purposes.

It also means that quick C-level operations on the elements is not available. When you perform an addition it has to do a dictionary lookup for `__add__` on the object and then call that Python function. Similarly, calling `np.abs` performs a dictionary lookup for `__abs__` on every element of the array, and then a Python function call. Similarly calling argmax involves a dictionary lookup for a comparison operator (probably `__lt__`) on every element. Obviously this stuff is time consuming, especially compared an array of pure C where each of these operations would probably be close to one processor instruction.

One way round this would be to create two arrays with a fixed size integer type (64 bit ideally) to represent the numerator and denominator of the fraction. (*Note: the type of a numpy array is given by `dtype`*). You'd need to implement to various arithmetic operations yourself in Cython but the fact that it's a single known datatype would give you a significant speed-up (alternately you could store them both in one array using a numpy structured array).

However:

### 2. The `Fraction` class uses arbitrary length integers

In order to avoid ever having to round anything the fraction class uses Python "long" integers, which can hold as large a number as you like (up to the limit of your memory) but which require an unknown amount of memory to do so.

The consequence of that is that it is not possible to allocate them in a contiguous array with a fixed size type (which is good for indexing speed). A second consequence is that it isn't possible to generate "fast" C code for them - during each operation it needs to work out how big the number currently is, look out for overflows, potentially allocate more memory.

The best solution for this is just to accept that you need to round somewhere and used a fixed-size data type. A second solution is probably to have an explicit "fast path" and "slow path". Store 4 arrays: numerator small, numerator large, denominator small, denominator large, with the small ones being of `dtype=np.int64` and the large ones being the generic `dtype=object`. Use the small ones if possible, and only resort to the large ones where an overflow occurs. Provided that the majority of your data is "small" this will probably be faster. Either option will require writing a lot of arithmetic code yourself.

Comment: This is a quality guidance I was looking for. Thank you.